# Можно ли использовать dllexport/dllimport в LIB, чтобы затем подключить LIB к DLL, а затем DLL к EXE?

Tags: c++, компиляция

Я бы хотел создать несколько LIB, в которых были бы определны классы/методы с dllexport/dllimport. Затем я бы хотел создать DLL, подключающую все эти LIB. После этого я бы хотел создать EXE, который мог бы использовать все методы, отмеченные dllexport/dllimport в LIB, подключая не их, а DLL.

Однако, когда я попробовал сделать это, компилятор, собирая LIB в DLL, удалил абсолютно всё их содержание, так как, вероятно, решил, что этот код не используется, ведь DLL нигде не вызывает ничего из содержимого LIBs. Она и не должна. Она должна только экспортировать эти методы. Как я думаю, это подтверждается тем, что если я в DllMain создам объект любого класса из LIB и вызову любой его метод, он будет экспортирован в DLL.

Я бы хотел узнать, возможно ли собрать проект таким образом и получить желаемый результат. Если да, то какие настройки компилятора при этом следует использовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что это очень похоже на [проблему X-Y](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/177993) - необходимо раскрыть цель совершения всех этих действий.

Comment: dll не может подключать lib "c коробки" по крайней мере. lib - это инструмент исключительно для компиляции. Если у вас проблема с "видимостью" то тогда проверяйте опции компилятора, например - связывать все экспортируемые функции - сделает так что итоговый lib будет с кодом. Опять же есть два вида lib - "пустой" и "полный". "пустой" - то что вам и нужно - он просто сделает ссылку на dll, а "полный" - наоборот прилинкует код к модулю.

Comment: Проблему с exe нужно рассматривать отдельным вопросом или абзацем от проблемы с dll. И очень чётко описать какая проблема с exe и какая проблема с dll. Написано всё путано, сложно понять с чем именно проблема.

Comment: В данном случае я не пытаюсь решить никакую конкретную проблему. Я просто хочу структурировать проект таким образом, чтобы он состоял из нескольких LIB, которые бы собирались в одну DLL, потому что если просто положить всё в одну DLL, то, очевидно, это будет собираться дольше. LIBы иDLL - это отдельные проекты. Я не имею ввиду файл LIB для DLL. Проблема заключается в том, что DLL не будет экспортировать то, что написано в LIBах, которые определены как его зависимости, даже если указано dllimport.

Comment: У вас уже на первом шаге начинается какая-то каша. Вот вы пишите *"Я бы хотел создать несколько LIB"* - файлы lib бывают либо статическими библиотеками, любо библиотеками импорта (для dll). Какой вариант у вас? И вообще, лучше сразу приводить [mcve].